# How to add UIView as a subview on UIViewController in UIStoryboard

Tags: objective-c, uistoryboard, subview, iphone-5, xcode5.1

Is there any way that I can add uiview as a subview over a view controller using UIStoryboard, using xib's we can do that, but i'm unable do that using storyboard.
 My storyboard is not holding any of the uiview as a subview when I drag and drop on it, it was placing under the view controller.
     Is there any way that I can add it programmatically on my view controller using storyboard.? I'm stuck please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Am I right, you want to hold UIView in storyboards without view controller or superview ?

You can't do that. You should use XIBs to hold custom views. 
It doesn't matter you add it programmatically or via drag and drop, in storyboards you can't hold "isolated" views, every view must have a superview and therefore a UIViewController.

Check apple's [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/Introduction/Introduction.html), make sure you understand UIViewController,UIView,UIStoryboard classes and relations between them. Also [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Hope it helped.

Comment: Nope i don't want to hold uiview without viewcontrollers on storyboards, i wanted is to keep the uiview under the view controllers, so that i can add as subview programatically, anyways i have done it, i'm able to add the uiview's as subview i just dragged that view under viewcontroller first responder i.e above the exit . and [self.view addsubview:myviewname] it worked out. Anyways thanks for your reply.Cheers

Comment: Hi, I have added the UIView above exit but unable to view it in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can override UIViewController's loadView method to do it as i have written code below.
Because loadView is the method which is called first of all other viewController's loading methods. So you can set it here.

Hope this will work for you as I have tested it on my code.

```
   - (void)loadView {
        self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        // enter your customization code here

    }
```

Answer (score -5):

write this line in function

```
-(void) ViewDidLoad:

[self.view addSubView:...];
```